# How to implement custom adapters properly?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am trying to wrap my head around implementing adapters properly and would like to know the ff:

1. Is it okay to pass an activity context to an adapter? I've read somewhere it is bad practice to pass around activity context and find it confusing.

---

2. In getting the parent view e.g to be used in SnackBar etc., is instantiating it via constructor like this 

   `` this.mRootView =
   ((Activity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.activity_country_search);` ``

   the right way or should it be instantiated in `onCreateViewHolder` and utilize the `View parent` parameter like this:

```

```
@Override
public CountryIssuingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_country_search_issuing_row, parent, false);

    this.mRootView = parent.findViewById(R.id.activity_country_search);
    return new CountryIssuingViewHolder(v, true);
}
```

---

3. Is it okay to implement snackbar in the adapter or should I use eventbus and show it via activity?

---

Current adapter implementation:

**Activity**

```
adapter = new CountryIssuingListAdapter(this, countryIssuingList, new 
CountryPhoneCodeAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Country item, View v) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("COUNTRY", gson.toJson(item));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

**Adapter**

```
public CountryIssuingListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Country> itemArrayList, CountryPhoneCodeAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.countryArrayList = itemArrayList;
    this.countryArrayListForSearch = new ArrayList<>();
    this.countryArrayListForSearch.addAll(itemArrayList);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.TAG = mContext.getClass().getSimpleName();
    this.mRootView = ((Activity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.activity_country_search);
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see anything bad here. But in most cases you don't need a `Context` inside an adapter

2-3. Do you use a `SnackBar` to diplay an event (e.g. click, swipe)? If so, then you should pass a listener to the adapter and implement it in an activity like you did for `OnItemClick`. This way the adapter's work is only to display items and **notify** about User's actions **but do not handle these actions**

P.S. I would argue about using an `EventBus` instead of listeners but that's not the topic